# Pressure applied by block

Tags: forces, pressure

Consider a cubical box of dimensions 50x10x30 (cms) denoting l*b*h respectively . Now if I take the weight of cubical box to be 50 N then what should be the pressure applied by the cubical box on the floor ?

My say in the question : I assume that we need to go ahead with pressure = force per unit area but what area should be considered ? Isn't there 3 combinations of the area that can be in contact with the floor namely - lxb , bxh and lxh ?

Attaching an image for further clarification .
[image: Problem Picture]

Comment: You are correct, there are three possibilities for pressure but I would say go with the one with 30cmx10cm base as it is facing the floor in the image

Comment: @QuantumYitian But is 50 cm not in contact with 30 cm ? Don't you think that combo should be used to find the pressure on major basis ? Well i assume that the 30 cm area is on the base alone and it's standing vertically .

Comment: When you posted the question last time (you are not supposed to repost btw. Reif the old question, so it's better! ) the exercise text said which side was on the floor. Read the instructions!

Comment: @Kuhlambo I deleted that question because it raised an assignment help kinda query and secondly it's not mentioned in the question about which side is on the floor , it just says to find in ' other two ways ' , if you saw that question , hope you get what i mean

Comment: You can always improve the question, and i an not sure. But it sounds like a dumb assignment, so here is my tip, there are only three ways you can put such a box on the floor which are really "different" just do all these.